# Add auto_increment in JPA entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity, jpa-2.0

I use this entity definition for JPA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "payment_transactions")
public class PaymentTransactions implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private Date date;

    @Column
    private Integer year;
    .....
    }
```

Table is successfully created:

```
CREATE TABLE `payment_transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
}
```

Table is successfully created.

But I would like MariaDB to auto-generate unique table key value. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `payment_transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
}
```

What is the proper way to configure this with JPA?

Comment: "auto_increment" requires IDENTITY strategy, just like any JPA docs would tell you

Comment: Like this? `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Comment: *Identity: Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column.*. [Link to the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#IDENTITY)